# Devise - RoR: error running rails generate devise:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can someone help me??

I'm following the "Getting Started" instruction from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise and when I run `rails generate devise:install` I got the following error (My ruby is version 1.8.3 and Rails 3.2.17):

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `re
quire': C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:452: syntax
error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
...ults mapping.name, strategies: mapping.strategies
                          ^
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime
.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:
in `require'
        from C:/Users/Adit/Documents/Rails/blog187/config/application.rb:7
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/command
s.rb:24:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/command
s.rb:24
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6
```

Comment: you really, really need to upgrade your version of Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The version of devise you are trying to use( Devise 3) isn't compatible with Ruby 1.8.3

If it is possible update your Ruby to 1.9.3 or newer.

Comment: I cant, the web host that I am using doesn't allow me to update Ruby, which means I'm stuck with this sh*t version. Thanks for answering. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Set devise in your Gemfile to a minor version. Try with 2.2.8 or any 2.2